# Is it true that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ , there exist infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $kn+1 , (k+1)n+1$ both are perfect squares ?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Is it true that for every $k\in\mathbb N$ , there exist infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $kn+1 , (k+1)n+1$ both are perfect squares ? What I have tried is that I have to necessarily solve $a^2-b^2=n$ for given $n$ ; but I can not proceed further .  Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: For every $k$, one solution is $16k+8$ , maybe this helps to construct more solutions for a fixed $k$.

Comment: @Peter: There's actually an infinite number of solutions. Give me a few minutes to type...  :)

Comment: Another solution for every $k$ is $256k^3+384k^2+176k+24$

Comment: I know, there's a Pell equation involved.

Comment: Congratulations. I did not think of Pell ...

Comment: @Peter: How in the world did you find those polynomials then? Brute-force?  :)

Comment: @Peter: Ah, I also used the pattern-finding approach to find the initial solution.

Comment: Correction : $n=16k+8$ multiplied with $(\frac{n}{4})^2-1$ gives another solution.

Comment: @Peter: Finally found a neat and short formula.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is ***Yes***.

> I. (*Update*)

The solution to,

$$\begin{aligned} 
kn+1 &= x^2\\
(k+1)n+1 &= y^2
\end{aligned}$$

is given by,

$$n = \frac{ -(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) + \alpha^{2(2m+1)}+\beta^{2(2m+1)} }{4k(k+1)}$$

where,

$$\alpha = \sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}\\
\beta = \sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}$$

For example, for $m=1,2,3,\dots$ we get,

$$\begin{aligned}
n &= 8 + 16 k \\
n &= 24 + 176 k + 384 k^2 + 256 k^3 \\
n &= 48 + 736 k + 3968 k^2 + 9472 k^3 + 10240 k^4 + 4096 k^5 
\end{aligned}$$

and so on.

> II. (*Old answer*)

$$\begin{aligned} 
kn+1 &= x^2\\
(k+1)n+1 &= y^2
\end{aligned}\tag1$$

Eliminate $n$ between them and we get the *Pell-like*,

$$(k+1)x^2-ky^2 = 1$$

We can get an infinite number of solutions using a transformation (discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574748/4781)). Let $p,\,q = 4k+1,\;4k+3$, then,

$$x = p u^2 + 2 k q u v + k (k+1) p v^2$$

$$y = q u^2 + 2 (k+1)p u v + k (k+1) q v^2$$

and $u,\color{brown}\pm v$ solve the ***Pell equation***,

$$u^2-k(k+1)v^2 = 1$$

This has initial solution,

$$u = 2 k+1,\quad v = 2$$

and an infinite more. Thus,

$$\begin{aligned}
n &= 8 + 16 k \\
n &= 24 + 176 k + 384 k^2 + 256 k^3 \\ 
n &= 48 + 736 k + 3968 k^2 + 9472 k^3 + 10240 k^4 + 4096 k^5 \\ 
n &= 80 + 2080 k + 20096 k^2 + 93952 k^3 + 235520 k^4 + 323584k^5 + 229376 k^6 + 65536 k^7
\end{aligned}$$

and so on for an ***infinite*** number of $n$ for any $k$.

Comment: I knew there was a simpler way to express $n$.