# On $4n+1 = x^2, 5n+1 = y^2$ and the Fibonacci numbers

Tags: diophantine-equations, fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers, golden-ratio

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609484/), I decided to look at the particular case,

$$4n+1 = x^2\\5n+1 = y^2$$

to be solved simultaneously. The solutions for $n,x,y$ are [A157459](https://oeis.org/A157459), [A007805](https://oeis.org/A007805), and [A049629](https://oeis.org/A049629), respectively,

$$\begin{aligned}
n_k &=  72, 23256, 7488432, 2411251920,\dots\\[2.5mm]
x_k &= \frac{F(6k+3)}{2}\\ &= 17, 305, 5473, 98209, 1762289, 31622993,\dots\\[2.5mm]
y_k &= \frac{-F(6k+1)+F(6k+5)}{4} = \frac{F(6k+2)+F(6k+4)}{4}\\ &= 19, 341, 6119, 109801, 1970299, 35355581,\dots
\end{aligned}$$

starting with $k=1$ and $F(k)$ are the ***Fibonacci numbers***.

Trying to find an expression for the $n_k$ in terms of the Fibonacci numbers, the only remaining possibilities are $F(6k)$ and $F(6k+6)$. After some fiddling, I found,

$$n_k =  \frac{-18+\phi^{12k+6}+\phi^{-(12k+6)}}{80} = \frac{F(6k)\,F(6k+6)}{16}\tag1$$

and where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the ***golden ratio***.

**Q:** How do we prove that the two expressions for $(1)$ are indeed equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fibonacci numbers are given in terms of $\phi$ by 
$$
F(n) = \frac{\phi^n - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$
Also note that for even $n$, $(-\phi)^{-n} = \phi^{-n}$.  This implies that
\begin{align*}
F(6k) F(6k+6) &= \frac{1}{5} (\phi^{6k} - \phi^{-6k})(\phi^{6k+6} - \phi^{-6k - 6}) \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \left[ \phi^{12k + 6} + \phi^{-(12k + 6)} - \phi^6 - \phi^{-6} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \left[ \phi^{12k + 6} + \phi^{-(12k + 6)} - 18 \right],
\end{align*}
since $\phi^6 + \phi^{-6} = 18$.  The given equality then follows.

**EDIT**:  Just to prove that $\phi^6 + \phi^{-6} = 18$:  note that
$$
(\phi^6 + \phi^{-6})(\phi^6 - \phi^{-6}) = \phi^{12} - \phi^{-12},
$$
from which it follows that 
$$
\phi^6 + \phi^{-6} = \frac{F(12)}{F(6)} = \frac{144}{6} = 18.
$$

Comment: Ahh, very nice.

Comment: Thanks to your pointing out that $\phi^6+\phi^{-6} = 18$, I found a short formula for the general case $kn+1 = x^2,\, (k+1)n+1 = y^2$. (I had puzzled how to express the constant in the numerator.) Kindly see the updated answer in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1609556/4781).